# On Clicking Radio Button image should change

Tags: jquery, html, phpmyadmin

I have 3 radio buttons and on clicking 1 st button it should call one image. On clicking 2nd button the first image should go away on clicking 3 second one should go away. I want to do it using jquery.. Please help me out

Comment: @SanketKotak, this question is very poor. You should provide more detail, some code, or some hint of personal effort on your part.

Answer (score 0):

you can see the code sample in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Eagjz/13/)

and here is the sample code. **However** I agree with everyone that you should have posted some sample code to show you were doing some thinking!!

```
div{
height:50px;
    width:50px;
}
.yellow{
background-color:yellow
}
.green{
background-color:green;
}
.blue{
background-color:blue;
}
.red{
background-color:red;
}
​
<ul>
    <li><input type='radio' id='1' name='change'><label>red</label></li>
    <li><input type='radio' id='2' name='change'><label>blue</label></li>
    <li><input type='radio' id='3' name='change'><label>green</label></li>

</ul>

<div id='show' class='yellow'></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul>li>input').change(function(index){
        console.log($(this));
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(id);
        var cssClass = 'yellow';
        switch(id)
        {
            case '1':
                cssClass = 'red';
                break;
            case '2':
                cssClass = 'blue';
                break;
            case '3':
                cssClass = 'green';
                break;
        }
        console.log(cssClass);
        $('#show').removeClass().addClass(cssClass);
    });
});​
```